# How to write unit test for WKWebView evaluateJavaScript

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, unit-testing, wkwebview

I want to do some unit test regarding **WKWebView evaluateJavaScript** JS code. JS code runs well in ViewController.m, but failed in unit test with error of "Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=5 "JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type}".

I change the JS code to a very simple string `@"(function(){return 5;})()"`, still failed.

```
// ViewController.m 
// works with result of 5

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    WKWebView *wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:configuration];
    wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:wkWebView];
    
    [wkWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html></html>" baseURL:nil];
    
    NSString *script = @"(function(){return 5;})()";
    [wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result] ;
        NSLog(@"Value %@ %@", value, error);
    }];
}
```

```
// unit test 
// failed with error of unsupported type
 
- (void)testExample {
    WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    WKWebView *wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,300) configuration:configuration];

    [wkWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html></html>" baseURL:nil];
    
    NSString *script = @"(function(){return 5;})()";
    [wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result] ;
        NSLog(@"Value %@ %@", value, error);
        XCTAssertEqualObjects(@"5", value, @"");
    }];
}
```